# Creating map series of unique extents (not grid shaped) with Spatial map series using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, map-series

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.8.

**Goal**: Create a map series with the first page being an overview of the study area, and the following pages being close-ups of areas I'm uniquely defining (e.g. these close-up extents aren't defined by a single feature and are at different map scales). Essentially, I have an overview map frame of the project site, and about 20 smaller areas within that each need a page. These 20 smaller areas are not defined by city boundaries, attributes, but was subjectively decided based on the presentation format.

**Problem**: I've created a bookmark map series with no problems. I added each bookmark in the working map space and then generated the map series onto a layout template. I thought this would be fine, but my colleague is asking for a *spatial* map series instead.

Is it possible to create a spatial map series of regions in my map that are each different sized areas, and don't all share the same features to sort by?

I thought about trying to make a *grid* spatial map series and taking out pages that don't contain relevant sites, but this could also result in my close-up areas being incorrectly indexed.

Each of the 20 smaller areas will also have another map frame extent to show where on the larger map that page is focused.

Comment: Dissolve small areas to one multiparr polygon. This is page 1. Append it by small polygons, to create the rest of pages.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. "Best" questions tend to be too  subjective for our Focused question/Best answer model. Often the "best" method of many is what makes the most sense to the decision-maker.

Comment: If you're using ArcMap then you're making a map series using Data Driven Pages.  If you're using ArcGIS Pro then you're making a map series using a Map Series.  In either event bookmarks can be converted to features making bookmark and spatial map series more or less interchangeable so the choice is yours.